# Is there a way to create custom x axis labels for a bar chart using ApexChart?

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I have an apex bar chart that will plot bar charts between a range of 0 and 12. There are 6 possible points and I need to be able to display a text that corresponds to these points.

For example:

Range 0 - 2 represents the value of "Alpha".

2 - 4: "Beta"

4 - 7: "Gamma"

7 - 11: "Delta"

12: "Epsilon"

How would I be able to add these custom points on the x-axis? (Also, for some reason 12 isn't shown at all as it's the last value?)

[image: Chart Example]